# Не могу работать с Nodejs в Termux

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, termux

При установке Mongoose и MongoDB выходит ошибку.

Что я ввожу:

`$npm install mongoose`

Что мне выдает:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/storage/emulated/0/Download/package.json'
npm WARN Download No description
npm WARN Download No repository field.
npm WARN Download No README data
npm WARN Download No license field.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../semver/bin/semver
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/Download/node_modules/.bin/semver
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../semver/bin/semver' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Download/node_modules/.bin/semver'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../semver/bin/semver' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Download/node_modules/.bin/semver'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../semver/bin/semver' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Download/node_modules/.bin/semver'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -1,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../semver/bin/semver',
npm ERR!     dest: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/node_modules/.bin/semver'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../semver/bin/semver',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/node_modules/.bin/semver'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2020-10-14T22_21_57_311Z-debug.log
```

Уже пробовал переустановить и терминал и Node.js

Comment: sudo rm -rf /storage/emulated/0/Download/node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Установите Termux-API. Точно не помню, как apk, или через команду **pkg install termux-api termux-tools**. Потом запустите команду **termux-setup-storage**.

Далее обращайтесь к папкам из storage не напрямую, а через ссылки внутри домашней папки termux.

[Подробнее про termux-setup-storage](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Internal_and_external_storage).

Также можно запустить команду **termux-chroot**. Это создаст линуксовое окружение так, что в корне файловой системы будут папки */usr*, */var*, */home* и прочие. Так удобнее работать.